# Android, php and JSON: send image to Android with json

Tags: php, android, json, base64

What I need to do is to sent (from php script) an image with a **JSON** message to an android app. On php, I encode image as:

```
$thumbnail = file_get_contents("http://graph.facebook.com/" . $current['username'] . "/picture");
$thumb_encoded = base64_encode($thumbnail);
```

and I get it from android with:

```
String image_base64 = jsonObj.getString("image");
```

It's correct to do like that, or I need to convert `$thumb_encoded` into string before sent it as a string with **json**?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need JSON?

Is it not simpler to do the following?

```
$url = "http://graph.facebook.com/" . $current['username'] . "/picture";
imagejpeg($im, $url);
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Comment: because my app send and receive json mesasge from my server

Answer (score 0):

You should add the correct header and encode your response :

```
$url = "http://graph.facebook.com/" . $current['username'] . "/picture";
$thumbnail = file_get_contents($url);
$encoded = base64_encode($thumbnail);

header('Content-Type: application/json');
// returns {"image":"iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEU...QmCC"}
echo json_encode(array('image' => $encoded));
```